# Users denied unsubscribe function

Tags: permissions

Using CiviCRM generated URLs in the mandatory footer of a Civimail bulk mailing users are presented with error:
CiviCRM
You do not have permission to access this content.

The url form is:
https://example.org.uk/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%252Fmailing%252Funsubscribe&reset=1&jid=8909&qid=254938&h=7be20f8b9c9c9389

Why are users being denied access?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to civicrm SE, Can you make sure if you have 'CiviMail: access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages' permission set to anonymous and autheticated sure?

Can Check under CiviCRM >> Administer >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions (Access Control) >>  WordPress Access Control

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, I've checked this and anon and all other user types are configured to have access.

Comment: Are you sure about the url?

Comment: I'm getting this behaviour as well. CiviCRM 5.17.2 on WordPress. http://www.brockwellgreenhouses.org.uk/civicrm?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Funsubscribe&reset=1&jid=8917&qid=256210&h=461367cc0b3bfa99